# Execution failed for task ':react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugKotlin'. (React Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native

[when I try to run npm run android it shows the errors as below]
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8m 20s

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tipZJ.png)

Why is this app not completing the build?